# How to get package icon in eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, package

I have a project on eclipse and I am wondering why I do not see the package symbol on the folders in the hierarchy.

Do I have to choose an option to be able to see the folders appear as package on eclipse?

I am using PyDev plugin here..

Answer (score 1):

Three things spring to mind:

- Does the project have a pythonpath set? Right-click the project -> properties -> pythonpath. Add the root project directory, or whatever is appropriate for your project.
- Do your packages contain an `__init__.py` file?
- Have you got a python interpreter configured in PyDev?
- Is your package explorer tab/window titled "PyDev Package Explorer"? If not, got to Window -> "Show View" -> "PyDev Package Explorer".
- Do you have the pydev builder enabled? (PyDev Settings -> Builders)

Comment: I have #2 and #3.My friend who has the same setup did not have to do #1 but she has a package symbol on her __init__.py also.

Comment: I dont get the package symbols but all seems to work fine..So i dont know if the symbol of the folder on the PyDev Package folder makes a difference or not.